# how to get the drop target from gwt-dnd

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop

I have a vertical panel containing two rows, say row 1 and row 2, each 
row contains couple of widgets, now i need to allow the user to drag 
and drop widgets between row 1 and row 2, here is what i did

```
   _handler = new DragHandler() { .... }; 
   _widgetDragController = new PickupDragController(boundaryPanel, false);
   _widgetDragController.setBehaviorMultipleSelection(false); 
   _widgetDragController.addDragHandler(_handler);
```

then for each row, create panel to hold widgets and assign a drop controller:

```
   VerticalPanelWithSpacer vPanel = new VerticalPanelWithSpacer(); 

   // initialize a widget drop controller for the current column VerticalPanelDropController

   widgetDropController = new VerticalPanelDropController(vPanel);   
   _widgetDragController.registerDropController(widgetDropController);
```

how can i find the drop target (namely which row) when i dnd widgets between row 1 and row 2? is there any way the _widgetDragController can tell which drop controller got involved and then i can further call getDropTarget() from the drop controller?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the functionality in VerticalPanelDropController.onDrop(DragContext), which gets called when the users drop on that drop controller. The drop controller knows the VerticalPanelWithSpacer it belongs to, and the dragContext contains information such as the x, y coordinates. You could use this information (the y coordinate & the coordinates of the widget) to calculate the row which should be added (although you might need to take scrolling etc into account, which makes it a bit more tricky). Hope that helps :-)